# How to change a SPECIFIC Mac desktop background

Tags: terminal, applescript

I use multiple desktops for multitasking on my Mac. I would like to know how to change desktop background of desktop *n* out of the total number of desktops. So far when I try this with command line:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value = '/path/to/file.JPG'";killall Dock
```

each of my 5 Desktop background changes. I have tried downloading a program to browse the desktoppicture.db file(Where the desktop picture is stored).

AppleScript and Terminal Command Line have been my langages of choice to attempt this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Applescript is not really suited for this ... however with a bit of bash/sqlite3 scripting, this is what I've come up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$2" ]; then
desktop=$2
else
desktop=0; #The Desktop that we are trying to change, 0 indexed with 0 being the first desktop created
fi
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
desktopLocation="$1"
else
desktopLocation="/Library/Desktop Pictures/Snow.jpg" #Where our Desktop is located
fi
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db "update data set value='$desktopLocation' where value like '%.%' LIMIT $desktop,1;"
```

Copy and paste that into a .sh file, and set the first argument to the location of the desktop background you want, and set the second argument to which desktop (in order of when they were created, 0 indexed) to assign it to. then run `killall Dock` in order to initiate the change